# extracting strings and merging using regex in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I Have a column value like :
{"extarctrule":[{"includescene":"includewhen","columnid":"product","columnoperator":"in","columnvalue":"cat dog"}],"includerule(text)":" {{This Rule applies When}} {{Product}} {{in}} cat dog","surplexrule":[{"surplexruletype":"available","scene":"initially"}],"surplexrule(text)":" {{Make Available}} {{Initially}}"}

i want the output like

This Rule applies When Product in cat dog Make Available initially

Comment: basically i need to extract between includerule(text)":" and "surplexrule" and removing the characters      and     extract after suplexrule(text)":" and removing the characters.

Comment: got the answer never mind....no one to see though